# ajax with manifest not workign

Tags: database, ajax, html, manifest, offline

I have a strange problem with my web app. It is app which loads data from database and than it can work offline (HTML5 database feature).

But when I added manifest file to made offline mode more powerful, ajax calls for loading data from server to client does't working anymore.

Does anybody know what can be reason for that? Does adding manifest file make ajax calls unusable?

nest

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to include any server-side AJAX files in the NETWORK section of your cache manifest.  This should let your AJAX calls work properly.  Note however that this will ONLY work when the user is online.  If they're running the application from cache and are offline, any AJAX calls will fail since the server is unavailable.